# Python remove files from folder which are not in list

Tags: python

I'm looking for help in below code where I can remove the files from the folder which not available in the given csv file.
I read the input file in the pandas' data frame and convert it into the list then
reading the fileName from the folder and comparing the fileName with the available file in the folder and if it exists continue if not remove. but it is removing all the files including the not matching files.

I only want to remove the files which are not present in the file I'm reading using pandas data frame.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = "Adwords/"

flist = pd.read_csv('C:/mediaops/mapping/adword/file_name.csv')

file_name = flist['fileName'].tolist()

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    print(filename)
    if filename == file_name:
        continue
    elif filename != file_name:
        os.remove(filename)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    print(filename)
    if filename not in file_name:
        os.remove(filename)
```

Answer (score 4):

In your original solution, you are trying to do `filename == file_name` and `filename != file_name`, but you cannot do that.

See `filename` is a `string` and `file_name` is a list, and you cannot use `==` to compare them, you need to use `membership` operators like `in` and `not in`, like `if filename not in file_name:` which I did in my answer below
(Thanks to [Tobias's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55968165/8591431))

Now since that is out of the window, now you can iterate through all files using [os.listdir](http://os.listdir), then use [os.remove](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove) to remove the necessary files, in addition using [os.path.join](http://os.path.join) to get the full path of the file!

```
import os

#List all files in path
for filename in os.listdir(path):
  
    #If file is not present in list
    if filename not in file_name:
        #Get full path of file and remove it
        full_file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
        os.remove(full_file_path)
```

Comment: You explain to OP what she already does, and then sneakily fix the _actual_ problem without any explanation.

Comment: Sorry but I did not get what you just said in the comment! @tobias_k Is something misleading or missing in my answer?

Comment: Well, OP's immediate problem is that she is using `==` and `!=` instead of `in` and `not in`. You fix that, but never point this out, let alone explain why, and instead explain lots of other things that OP already does correctly. Good point about `os.path.join`, though.

Comment: Much better. :-)

Comment: Yes, I just explained it, but I want to give credit to your answer! How do I find the link to your answer to do that @tobias_k

Comment: Fixed the link! Apologies for that! I am new here and as much as I try to explain what the problem in OP's original solution is, sometimes I get too carried away and skip that! So thanks for pointing that out dear sir @tobias_k

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `file_name` is a `list` if string, whereas `filename` is a single string, so the check `filename != file_name` will *always* be true and the file thus *always* be removed. Instead, use `in` and `not in` to check whether the string is (not) in the list of strings. Also, using a `set` would be faster. Also, those variable names are *really* confusing.

```
set_of_files = set(file_name)
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename not in set_of_files:
        os.remove(filename)
```

Also, as noted in [Devesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55968052/1639625), you may have to `join` the filename to the path in order to be able to actually remove the file.

Answer (score 0):

when I implemented these answers it deleted all files in the dir, not in my list. So I wrote one for any weary traveler that may need this script. User needs to add in the path for where their files are and make a csvfile with the basename of the files that they want to keep. you can also add in the extention of the files that you want to look at if they happen to all the same.

The process is making the csv into a list based on each element in the first column and then checking to see if the files in the current dir are present in the list. If they are not then remove.

```html
import os
import csv
import argparse
import sys
import pathlib

data_path = path = "/path/to/your/dir"
csv_guide = "filenamestokeep.csv"
csv_path = os.path.join(data_path, csv_guide)
ext = "input.your.extention.of.files.to.look.at.as.ext, like .txt"
with open(csv_path, 'r') as csvfile:
    good_files = []
    for n in csv.reader(csvfile):
        if len(n) > 0: good_files.append(n[0])
    print(good_files)
    all_files = os.listdir(data_path)
    for filename in all_files:
        if filename.endswith(ext) and filename not in good_files:
            print(filename)
            full_file_path = os.path.join(data_path, filename)
            print("File to delete: {} ".format(filename))
            os.remove(full_file_path)
        else:
           print(f"Ignored -- {filename}")
```